# Unable to use fill_between in matplotlib basic ploting

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

How to fill the following region:

```
(x < 100) & (y > 10)

import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0,255,0.1)
y = np.arange(0,255,0.1)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.fill_between(range(0,100), range(10,100),color='r',alpha=.3)
plt.show()
```

ValueError: Argument dimensions are incompatible

nope!

Comment: Yup! `range(0,100)` and `range(10,100)` don't have the same dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you need masked arrays for that.. I'm not sure if this completely matches your goal, but e.g.:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0,255,0.1)
y = np.arange(0,255,0.1)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.fill_between(x, y1=10, y2=255, where=x<100)  
plt.show()
```

Comment: its correct for the lower range, but not for upper range since it's not filling the rectangle region.

Comment: But with `(x < 100) & (y > 10)`, what is the upper limit of `y`, and lower limit of `x`?

Comment: y between 10 and 255. x between 0 and 100.

Comment: `plt.fill_between(x, y1=10, y2=255, where=x<100)`?

Comment: But in that case, you might also simply draw a filled rectangle

Comment: yes its correct. Nevertheless I prefer using conditional. Could you give me bonus..

Comment: What do you mean with 'conditional'?

Comment: That would be something like `m = x<100` and `plt.fill_between(x[m], y1=10, y2=255)`, but then I would prefer my method using the `where` argument of `fill_between`